# joomla 3.6.5 confirm shop with one step only without virtuemart

Tags: joomla, checkout

I want to change the confirmation shop page with only one step, and I don't use virtuemart, I use GDW.

If someone have the same problem please show me the solution.

Comment: what is GDW? You will have to edit the checkout page to have a single step.

Comment: GDW is like virtuemart.It is a plugin.

Comment: Can't even find it on the [Joomla Extension Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/?searchall=gdw&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1), how can we help if there is nothing to work on? Post some code perhaps...

Comment: It's a Canadian plugin, this link can help https://www.geantduweb.ca/

Comment: That's the name of the company, you will have to ask them how to make the change because it seems like it is custom developed and belongs to them